# Fixing bad conflict resolution after wrong merge from master into my feature branch

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a feature branch only I'm working on.

I made a merge from master into my feature branch, to keep it up-to-date, and accidentally solved conflicts wrong.

Kept working on my feature and pushed more changes. How can I revert things to: not bring in the bad "resolved conflicts" into my feature branch?

Essentially what I want to do is to make sure I am in my current branch in the following state:

1/ exactly as I was before I did the bad merge conflict resolution ;

And

2/ somehow I want to be able to, from the state I'll be after doing 1,still apply the changes I've done after my bad merge, maybe using a cherry pick on each individual commit or something...

I read that maybe an interactive rebase can be what I need but I've never done it.... Any help appreciated.

I tired to do a `git revert <SHA1 of the merge commit>` that I saw in `git reflog` but that didn't work as I need to pass the parent ID commit with the `-m` flag but doing that didn't revert what I was expecting.

What I think I want to do now is: go back to one commit right before I did this bad merge from master into my feature branch and then I want to interactively cherry pick which commits to apply to this new current state as if I can do that, I can then "skip" over the bad merge commit. Obviously I'll then have to merge master into the branch again but then I'll be careful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the best practice is, if you are the only one working on `feature` branch, to rebase `feature` branch on top of `master` when you want to update it with `master` content.
Not to merge `master` to `feature`.

You merge topic branches to integration branches (like `master`), not the opposite. That way, you can "move around" (rebase/replay) your feature branch without bringing with said feature branch a huge merge commit from the integration branch (master, which, as an integration branch, brings a all lot of *other* branches).

Second, you can `git reset --hard` your feature branch to before the merge, redo the merge, and then replay (rebase) your subsequent commits

```
git switch feature

# mark what the old history looked like before reset
# First feature branch as tmp
git branch tmp
# Then the bad merge commit
git tag merge-commit <sha1-merge-commit>

# reset your branch to before the bad merge commit
git switch -C feature merge-commit~
# redo the merge

# Then restore your work
git rebase --onto feature merge-commit tmp
git switch feature
git merge tmp

# cleanup
git branch -f tmp
git tag -d merge-commit

git push --force feature
```

Answer (score 0):

Well...... there are two parts to this process. The first is called **"correcting the wrong merge"**. You can either retry the merge from scratch.... or you can amend the one you did before to correct some mistakes. Let's say that the bad merge is commit `X`.

First way would be:

```
git checkout X~
git merge X^2
# correct all conflicts
git add .
git commit -C X # use the same commend as the original X
```

Second approach is

```
git checkout X
# do the necessary adjustments by comparing with the parents and so on
git add .
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Either way, you are now standing on the *corrected* X and we have to go into the second step, which is pretty appropriately called **"the second step"**.... we cherry-pick whatever you put on top of X

```
git cherry-pick X..feature-branch
# if you like the result
git branch -f feature-branch
git checkout feature-branch
```

And that's it.